# SQL oracle SUM function with conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table that looks like this

```
TIMECODE  UNIT_CODE   Department   Account      AMOUNT  
20194        10        1000             1000     100     
20194        10        2354             1100     150        
20194        10        1000             1000     200         
20194        10        2354             1000     100          
20194        20        500              1000     250         
20194        20        500              1100     200
```

How I need the results to be is like this

```
TIMECODE  UNIT_CODE   Department   1000      1100  
20194        10        1000        300       NULL     
20194        10        2354        100       150                
20194        20        500         250       200
```

hopefully that gives you a better image, but basically I would need to do a SUM depending on the distinct value of the other columns. The accounts that were previously in rows would be changed into columns.

any ideas or help with this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=28e1db53d5c74b26693a92ce85f29c1f).

```
select
    TIMECODE,
    UNIT_CODE,
    Department,
    sum(case when Account = 1000 then AMOUNT end) as "1000",
    sum(case when Account = 1100 then AMOUNT end) as "1100"
from myTable
group by
    TIMECODE,
    UNIT_CODE,
    Department
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| TIMECODE    UNIT_CODE   DEPARTMENT  1000    1100 |
---------------------------------------------------
|  20194          20          500      250     200 |
|  20194          10          1000     300     null|
|  20194          10          2354     100     150 |
---------------------------------------------------
```